# How to compare the difference for the last row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, row-number

I have a view and this is the result of it:

```
ID  Type  Time                                RowNum
18  2     2015-12-14 12:15:00.9330000 +00:00  214
18  6     2015-12-14 12:21:22.4330000 +00:00  215
18  2     2015-12-15 09:04:41.2870000 +00:00  216
18  6     2015-12-15 09:06:22.9400000 +00:00  217
18  5     2015-12-15 09:07:28.0130000 +00:00  218
```

I am trying to compare the time difference between rows and group by the type by using the query below. My issue is for the last row I want to get the difference wth the current time and calculate the sum of difference. This is the query am using. How to compare only for the last row with the current time and calculate the sum:

```
WITH rows AS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[View])
SELECT  p.ID ,
        p.Type ,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.Time, q.Time))
FROM    rows p
        JOIN rows q ON p.RowNum = q.RowNum - 1
GROUP BY p.ID ,
         p.Type
```

Comment: What is the version of `Sql Server`?

Comment: Isn't this the same, logically, as just taking the `DATEDIFF` in seconds between the *earliest* entry and the current date? Why split this up into calculating the differences between all rows and summing them?

Comment: Use the `lag()` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever - I need to group by the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `ISNULL` function:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      Type INT ,
      Time DATETIMEOFFSET ,
      RowNum INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 18, 2, '2015-12-14 12:15:00.9330000 +00:00', 214 ),
        ( 18, 6, '2015-12-14 12:21:22.4330000 +00:00', 215 ),
        ( 18, 2, '2015-12-15 09:04:41.2870000 +00:00', 216 ),
        ( 18, 6, '2015-12-15 09:06:22.9400000 +00:00', 217 ),
        ( 18, 5, '2015-12-15 09:07:28.0130000 +00:00', 218 );

SELECT  p.ID ,
        p.Type ,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, p.Time, ISNULL(q.Time, GETDATE())))
FROM    @t p
        LEFT JOIN @t q ON p.RowNum = q.RowNum - 1
GROUP BY p.ID ,
         p.Type
```

Output:

```
18  2   483
18  5   21186
18  6   74665
```

Comment: This works..Only issue am getting a negative value for the Type 5 with the same data

Comment: @Hariharan, it may be because of data, can you give a set where the select gives negative value?

Comment: It is for the same data...The input time is in UTC. So I changed the GETDATE here to GetUTCDATE. It shows the expected value. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or above this will work

```
;WITH CTE AS
(

SELECT
 a.ID
,a.Type
,a.Time,
ISNULL(LEAD(a.Time) OVER (Order by RowNum ASC),GETDATE()) AS NextTime
FROM
 FROM [dbo].[View] a
)
SELECT
         ID,
        Type,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CTE.Time, CTE.NextTime))
FROM CTE
GROUP BY
ID,
Type
```

**Reference for LEAD()**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213125.aspx